# how to install Marklogic RSS FEED sample application

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to learn how RSS FEEDs can be configured in marklogic so that it pulls data from RSS feeds and stores in marklogic database.

There is "read me" file for for rss feed instrution in http://developer.marklogic.com/code/feed, but I have don't any idea how to install the sample application and see what are the basic capabilities. Could anyone help me how to install sample application ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That Feed project is more of a library than an application. Despite the sample app, it won't do much unless you write more code around it. The library exposes a few functions for subscribing, unsubscribing, etc. There are extensive comments for the public functions, on lines 80-500 of [feed.xqy](https://github.com/marklogic/feed/blob/master/lib/feed.xqy). Read those comments and you should have you a good idea of its capabilities.

Installing the Feed library means making its code available to your application. The instructions at https://github.com/marklogic/feed cover that topic if you are reasonably familiar with MarkLogic.

> Install the feed directory at the root level of the
>   application server. The Task Server 'time limit' must be configured to
>   allow reasonable time  to make http requests for feed documents.
>
> This API requires the dates module from commons. The dates module
>   should  also be installed at the server root.
>
> Both the feed and dates modules can be installed in other directories,
>   but the references to the modules must be modified accordingly.
>
> This API requires a directory that the library can read and write to.
>   Currently this directory is set to /var/tmp. This setting can be
>   changed in feed/lib/feed.xqy
>
> This API requires xdmp:eval, xdmp:invoke, xdmp:spawn, and xdmp:save
>   permissions.

If you aren't already familiar with MarkLogic, http://developer.marklogic.com/learn/technical-overview is a good place to start.

Comment: You could also reach out to http://www.linkedin.com/in/jasonmonberg who wrote it.

Comment: And note that you'll need, likely, an app server configured to default 0.9-ml XQuery dialect, since this code is old.